# how to create after receiving local notification data pass to Main view controller using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

I have creating local notification process using objective C for iPhone application. I want to pass the data after `didReceiveLocalNotification` to Main view controller.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {


    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive ) {
        NSLog(@"app not running");

       // I need to pass the data to main view controller 


    }else if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )  {
        NSLog(@"app running");


        // I need to pass the data to main view controller

    }

    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);  // Handle the notificaton when the app is running 

}
```

Comment: please show your navigation stack like how you create your flow.

Comment: I have created custome navigation process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use NSNotificationCenter to pass data.

in **MainViewController.m**

in `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notifMainController:) name:@"notifMainController" object:nil];

-(void)notifMainController:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"%@",notif.object);
}
```

in AppDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif 
{

 NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);  // Handle the notificaton when the app is running 

if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive ) 
{
    NSLog(@"app not running");
   // I need to pass the data to main view controller 
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            MainViewController *obj = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navC pushViewController:obj animated:NO];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifMainController" object:@"your string"];
        });

}
else if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )  
{
    NSLog(@"app running");
    // I need to pass the data to main view controller
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifMainController" object:@"your string"];
}

}
```

you can pass string in `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifMainController" object:@"your string"];` like this in object.
Maybe this will help you.

Comment: How can I send the data to third view controller from Appdelegate. I have programmatically created everything in my app code.

Comment: @Mano i wrote all code. i've added nsnotificationcenter and using NSNotitification you can send data. please read whole answer.

Comment: @Mano if answer is helpful then upvote or accept is as answer.

Comment: sure I did vote this....I need another one doubt..I want to pass string value but there notif.object via how can i send..Please send your answer...

Comment: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"notifMainController" object:@"string"];
` you can send string in object and in `notifMainController:` method you'll get string in `notif.object`.

Comment: @Mano check out my updated answer. you can send any object when you postnotification with object.

Comment: Also: Here is a great article about it: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Comment: wow nice @Antzi..Actually I have received notifcation data into the main view controller but i dont know how to comapre my table data and notification data both are same or not. if both are same mean i need to change the tableview cell color. Do you have any idea about that...?

Comment: @Mano you can ask another question with your issue regarding that and SO people will help you. but for that you should try your self first and then ask question